# java -version not working in linux

Tags: linux, java

I have untar the jdk on my Linux machine and I have set the environment variables ie ~/.bash_profile

however if i give java -version on terminal I receive the below error.

bash: /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java: cannot execute binary file

Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: However echo $JAVA_HOME works fine. please let me how to fix, its RHEL 6

Comment: What's the output of `ldd /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java`? Possible 32 vs 64 bit mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Instead of untaring Java, try this

1. Remove all references to Java, and then the files and folders you untared
2. Run this as root `yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk`

There, now JRE 7 is installed, and `java -v` or `java -version` will work